# static objects.. when i load page in other browser its taking same objects value rather initializing to another instance of object

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

where my aspx.cs's page Load method goes like this

```
namespace BHELDISP
{
    public partial class welcomeuser : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    DataClass obj = DataClass.getObj();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    if (obj.getdate1() != null&&obj.getdate2() != null)//here is my problem where if load in other browser also this if getting executed  
                    {                           //instead of else, i think its because of static object..but how can resolve this one

                    //doing some calculation..

                    }
                    else
                    {
                   obj.setdate(txtdate1.Text);//first text box
                    }
         }

    }
}
```

and here i am having a business layer where i store data as follws in static object

```
namespace bal
{

   public class DataClass
    {
    public string date1;
    public string date2;
    static public DataClass dcobj;

    static public DataClass getObj()
        {
            if (dcobj == null)
            {
                dcobj = new DataClass();
                return dcobj;
            }
            return dcobj;

        }


    public string getdate1()
        {
            return date1;
        }


        public void setdate1(string date1)//store date1
        {
            this.date1 = date1;
        }

     }  
}
```

I having a problem with this static object , where if i load page in another Browser its getting the values of same

Please can any one can help me out
thank u in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your question is, but just try to keep in mind that static variables are members of the class itself (the type). Here is a reference on [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

I hope this helps a bit.